# How to prevent auto closing of ionic sliding item when button clicked on ion item options?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a product list that consisted of sliding ion items. My ion-item-options are like following;

```
<ion-item-options>
              <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="decreaseAmount(product.id)">
              <ion-icon name="md-remove"></ion-icon>
                </button>

              <ion-input disabled="true" id="amount" class="amount" type="number" [value]="product.amount"></ion-input>

              <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="increaseAmount(product.id)">
              <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
              </button>

              <button (click)="addToCart()" ion-button color="secondary">
              <ion-icon name="md-checkmark"></ion-icon>
              </button>

      </ion-item-options>
```

Basically, The buttons are using to increase or decrease the amount of the product. However, when I click one of the buttons to change the amount, sliding item closes itself. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Add $event to the operation methods:

**HTML**

```
....decreaseAmount($event, product.id)...
```

Class:

```
decreaseAmount(event, id){
  event.stopPropagation();
  .... // as before
}
```

This will stop the bubbling

Comment: event.preventDefault()?